# Need Online Tool to Convert GZip compression text to ASCII (Readable) text

Tags: redis, gzip, lettuce

I am trying to view data in a Redis database.
It is compressed data using Lettuce 6.1.1 version compression library.
It uses a GZIP compression type.
I have tried several online tools to convert the GZIP text to a readable ASCII format.
The tools fail because it does not recognize the GZIP text as GZIP data.  Maybe it has something to do with the compression algorithm lettuce uses to compress the data.

Can anyone point me to a tool where I can decompress this data to readable ascii text?

Here is an example of the compressed data:

> \x1F\x8B\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xABV*N-*\xCBLNu,JM\xF4+\xCDMJ-R\xB2R2604\xB44Q\xAA\x05\x00\x190\x9B\xD1\x1E\x00\x00\x00

This should translate to a number: 301194

Here is a second example:

> 1.\x1F\x8B\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x003602\xB04\x01\x00\x93\xC0t\xC3\x06\x00\x00\x00
> 2.\x1F\x8B\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x003602\xB0\xB0\x04\x00o\x8D\xDE\xA4\x06\x00\x00\x00
> 3.\x1F\x8B\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x003602\xB04\x07\x00)\x91}Z\x06\x00\x00\x00
> 4.\x1F\x8B\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x003602\xB04\x03\x00\xBF\xA1z-\x06\x00\x00\x00
> 5.\x1F\x8B\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x003602\xB04\x00\x00\x8A\x04\x19\xC4\x06\x00\x00\x00
> 6.\x1F\x8B\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x003602\xB04\x02\x00\xA6e\x17*\x06\x00\x00\x00
> 7.\x1F\x8B\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x003604\xB44\x01\x00J\x05\x03\xD0\x06\x00\x00\x00

This should be a list of 7 service area numbers.
Not sure of the order but the values should be:

> 1. 302090
> 2. 302092
> 3. 302097
> 4. 302094
> 5. 302096
> 6. 302089
> 7. 301194

I tried using this online tool:
https://codebeautify.org/gzip-decompress-online
There is no translation that appears in the translation window and no error is shown.

I also tried a this website:
https://www.multiutil.com/gzip-to-text-decompress/

I get the error: Invalid compression text
[image]

UPDATE
The RedisInsight screenshot below shows the key-value information. The value information that is compressed as gzip I would like to translate.
[image]

I wanted to copy the value that I have highlighted and decompress it so I can document what is stored in the database.

Comment: You need to provide actual information in your question. How exactly do the tools "fail"? What tools are you using? How? What error message do you get? Provide the first 30 or so bytes of the data you are trying to decompress in hex or base64 in the question.

Comment: Updated the information

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your examples 1 through 7. They are all valid gzip streams that decompress to:

1. `302094`
2. `302089`
3. `302097`
4. `302096`
5. `302090`
6. `302092`
7. `301194`

Your first example in your question however has an error in the integtity check at the end. It decodes to:

0. `{#eviceAreaNumber":"301194"}`

While the deflate compressed data in the gzip stream is valid, the CRC that follows it is not. The uncompressed length after that is incorrect as well.

The online tools you point to are expecting Base64 encoded data. Not the partial hex encodings you are trying there.

Comment: Thanks for this information.
Are you using a tool to translate the gzip data?
How can I translate the other data in the database?

Comment: Yes. The tool is called "gzip". It's already installed on every Unix system.

Comment: I don't have access to a Unix system.  Is there an online tool equivalent to the gzip tool?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. What kind of system are you using? I mentioned Unix, since it seems like that's what redis runs on.

Comment: I added a screenshot above to show what I want to translate.  I am using RedisInsight and do not have access to the development server. I would like to copy the value shown above and translate it to document what is stored in each key.